# Import Error in NLTK: Cannot import name compat

Tags: python, nlp

I am using 'nltk' installed by pip in my project. It works fine in local But when I tried to deploy in google appengine , It shows the Import error 'Cannot import name compat'. How to resolve it? Thanks in advance

update: the code

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk, tree2conlltags

sentence = "Hi , This week has been crazy. My report is on IBM. Can you give it a quick read and provide some feedback. She is in London. John  lives in New   York  and works for the European Union."

ne_tree = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)))
iob_tagged = tree2conlltags(ne_tree)
print iob_tagged
name = []
for chunk in iob_tagged:
    if chunk[2] != 'O':
        name.append(chunk[2])
    else:
        name.append(chunk[0])
print name
```

The error

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet, words
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~/prod-2582.413469289899104484/lib/nltk/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
from nltk.stem import *
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~/prod-2582.413469289899104484/lib/nltk/stem/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~/prod-2582.413469289899104484/lib/nltk/stem/snowball.py", line 31, in <module>
from nltk import compat
ImportError: cannot import name compat
```

Comment: Please copy-and-paste code, don't paste an image.

Comment: please add your code to this question

Answer (score 0):

Try and upgrading your ntlk package:

`pip install --upgrade nltk`

fixed this problem in my case

Comment: try and upgrade your pip as well `pip install --upgrade pip` and then upgrade `ntlk` as in the answer